# SSRS parameter - send null value in POST request

Tags: post, reporting-services, null, ssrs-2016

I need to get SSRS report [through a Form POST Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/application-integration/integrating-reporting-services-using-url-access-web-application?view=sql-server-ver16#url-access-through-a-form-post-method).
Everything work as expected (when defining input names and values) with one exception - I can't figure out how to set null as value. I tried set "Null", "IsNull=True", ":IsNull=True", "-1" and "".

Everything cause Report to show only error msg:

"The value provided for the report parameter 'ParamName' is not valid for its type. (rsReportParameterTypeMismatch)"

When I get report through URL GET method, i put ":IsNull=True" there in case of null is desired. So it looks like example.com/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fOB%20test/report7&rs:Command=Render&**ParamName:IsNull=True**

What should I set for value in input for report through a POST Method?

Thanks!

Note: Reason for usage of POST Method for me is URL length limit...